# Select specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, selection

I've a scientist dataframe

```
     radius      date     spin  atom
0    12,50       YYYY/MM   0     he
1    11,23       YYYY/MM   2     c
2    45,2        YYYY/MM   1     z
3    11,1        YYYY/MM   1     p
```

I want select for each row, all rows where the difference between the radius is under, for exemple 5

I've define a function to calc (simple,it's an example):

```
def diff_radius (a,b)
    return a-b
```

Is-it possible for each rows to find some rows which check the condition in calling an external function?

I try some way, not working:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
     ....
     df_in_radius=df.apply(lambda x : diff_radius(df[i]['radius'],x['radius']))
```

Can you help me?

Comment: i suppose is not a comma but a dot for radius?

Comment: and could you precise the difference between the radius and 'something' is under 5?

Comment: sorry i 've got a mistake  :  df_in_radius=df.apply(lambda x : diff_radius(df[i]['radius'],x['radius']) < 5)   i want for each row build a dataframe (with same columns) where difference between radius of loc[i] is under 5

Comment: sorry, I have a global dataframe.For each row (call "i") I want to select, in the same dataframe rows whose difference with the radius of "i" is less than 5.

This treatment is in a loop. "i" varies from 0 to the length of the dataframe.

Comment: please modify your question with all beginning hypotheses , because nobody understand....for example we have to guess you have a global dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the datatype of the `radius` column is a `tuple`. You can keep the `diff_radius` method like

```
def diff_radius(x):
    a, b = x
    return a-b
```

Then, you can use `loc` method in pandas to select the rows which matches the condition of radius differece less than 5.

```
df.loc[df.radius.apply(diff_radius) < 5]
```

**Edit #1**

If the datatype of the `radius` column is a `string`, then split them and typecast. The logic will go in the `diff_radius` method. In case of `string`

```
def diff_radius(x):
    x_split = x.split(',')
    a,b = int(x_split[0]), int(x_split[-1])
    return a-b
```

Comment: col radius isn't a tuple. This is the value of my element radius.   i put a comma not a point sorry.

Comment: @oxthon I have updated my answer for `string`. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I misspoke.

My dataframe is :

```
     radius of my atom      date     spin  atom
0    12.50                  YYYY/MM   0     he
1    11.23                  YYYY/MM   2     c
2    45.2                   YYYY/MM   1     z
3    11.1                   YYYY/MM   1     p
```

I do a loop , to apply on one row a special calcul of each row whose respond condition.
Example:

```
def diff_radius(current_row,x):
    current_row['radius']-x['radius']
    return a-b

df=pd.read_csv(csvfile,delimiter=";",names=('radius','date','spin','atom'))
# for each row of original dataframe
for i in range(df.shape[0]):

      # first build a new and tmp dataframe with row
      # which have a radius less 5 than df.iloc[i]['radius] (level of loop)
      df_tmp=df[diff_radius(df.iloc[i]['radius],df['radius']) <5]
      ....
      # start of special calc, with the df_tmp which contains all of rows
      # less 5 than the current row **(i)**
```

I thank you sincerely for your answers